# How do I use sed to delete a bunch of lines based on a pattern that repeats?

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I have a file with content like this:

```
[device]  
type=alpha  
instance=0  

[device]  
type=beta  
instance=1  

[device]  
type=gamma  
instance=2
```

I am trying to figure how to delete the lines

```
[device]  
type=beta  
instance=1
```

I am unable to use range delete between [device] and instance=2 since it removes the first device section.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to first replace all the new lines with some unique character (e.g. `!`) and then pass it through sed as shown below:

```
tr '\n' '!' < file.txt | sed 's/\[device\]!type=beta!instance=1//g' | tr '!' '\n'
```

Alternatively, you can perform a [multi-line search and replace](http://austinmatzko.com/2008/04/26/sed-multi-line-search-and-replace/) using just `sed`:

```
sed -n '
# if the first line copy the pattern to the hold buffer
1h
# if not the first line then append the pattern to the hold buffer
1!H
# if the last line then ...
$ {
        # copy from the hold to the pattern buffer
        g
        # do the search and replace
        s/\[device\]\ntype=beta\ninstance=1//g
        # print
        p
}
' file.txt
```